# wordpress redirection from header.php not working

Tags: wordpress, redirect, header, location

Nobody access my full wordpress website without login, if user is not logined than redirect it to `http://example/submit-project/`.

I'm trying to do this with this code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); $crntusr = $current_user; if($crntusr->ID == 0){ wp_redirect( 'example.com/login'; ); }
```

But get this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/content/n3pnexwpnas02_data02/36/3929936/html/wp-content/themes/freelanceengine/header.php:14)
>   in
>   /home/content/n3pnexwpnas02_data02/36/3929936/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1195

Comment: What code do you have at the line 14 in your header.php?

Comment: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   $crntusr =  $current_user;
   if($crntusr->ID == 0){
    
 wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/login' );
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit.

2) you should make an redirect before your template output something.

3) Better to refrain from using absolute links like `http://example.com`, you can get your WP login page via wp_login_url() function.

Remove your redirect code from your header.php file and try to add this code to your functions.php:

```
add_action ('wp_loaded', 'my_custom_redirect');
function my_custom_redirect() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() and !in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php')) ) {
        wp_redirect(wp_login_url()); 
        exit;
}    
}
```

Update.
If your login form is on custom page (http://example/submit-project/), then you should use this code:

```
add_action ('wp_loaded', 'my_custom_redirect');
function my_custom_redirect() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/submit-project/' ) {
        wp_redirect('http://example/submit-project/'); 
        exit;
}    
}
```

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/n3pnexwpnas02_data02/36/3929936/html/wp-content/themes/freelanceengine/header.php:15) in /home/content/n3pnexwpnas02_data02/36/3929936/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1195

Comment: nobody access my full wordpress website without login .if user is not login than redirect to   "wp_redirect('http://example.com/login');" this page.

Comment: thanks Alex it works but i want to give my custom login page url.

Comment: how to change wp login url

Comment: i changed my wp_login_url() its not working .it will be redirected to default admin login page

Comment: this error is display on the screen https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9uqoluJ-ZTLcy05YUVrWlBZUFE/view?usp=drivesdk